# static method constant in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, swift

In objective-c I have this code

```
- (void)foo
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Title";

    //some code
}
```

This code allow to alloc memory for identifier once and use it only in method scope. This was very useful when methods calls often.

How can I do it in swift with memory economy?

Comment: Stack memory allocations are essentially free, all that happens is the stack pointer is moved further. this is vastly different than heap allocations. Also per Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."

Comment: A more typical usage of a static in a meathod/function is to set assign the value only once but to also allow the value to be updated. Ex: - `(int)x {` `static int y = 0;` `return y += 1;` `}` This will return incrementing values starting at 1. A let will not do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a memory usage standpoint, this is arguably less optimal than omitting the static keyword.  The static keyword means the memory must always be allocated, even if the function is never called and is primarily intended for values you wish to change and maintain between function calls.

That said, the closest equivalent in your use case would be to use the "let" keyword which tells the compiler it will never change and allows the maximum freedom in optimization:

```
func foo() {
    let identifier = "Title"
    ...
}
```

Comment: While you're statement about static storage has merit in sone instances in the case of a static string in particular it will be in memory either way: it has to exist somewhere.

Comment: While you're statement about static storage has merit in sone instances in the case of a static string in particular it will be in memory either way: it has to exist somewhere. There are other things to consider such as is the string copied or just pointed to, in the first case there would be a cipy each time thefunction was entered. All in all, any such optimizations are foolish at best.

Comment: Hence "arguably". If you're doing it as an optimization, you're better off letting any modern compiler handle it.

Comment: But in this case, the variable will be allocated every time the function is called.

Comment: Yes, on the stack, and then discarded when the function returns. Although as @Zaph says, the text of the string (a single copy) will have been stored somewhere by the compiler.